# What is the meaning of this operator with three dots in my reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My reducer looks like this:

```
export const setName = action => {
  return {
    type: "SET_NAME",
    ...action
  };
};
```

what are these 3 dots and reducer doing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Try `console.log(action)` and then `console.log(...action)` and it should help you visualise what the spread operator does. Also the docs @SagarJajoriya linked above should help too.

Comment: It's the same as `Object.assign({}, {type: "SET_NAME"}, action)`

Answer (score 1):

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

**Example with function:**

```
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(sum(...numbers));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
```

**Example with object**

```
let a = {a: 1};
let b = {...a, b: 2};

console.log(b) //will print {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Think about it  like unzipping one object into another.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Ok, I got your point but in my question action is something which is iterating?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is spread operator which preserves original object and adds new elements to new object. For example

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var refColors = [...colors, 'yellow'];
//colors=> ['red', 'green', 'blue']
//refColors => ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think, this code is an `action creator` and not a `reducer`.

Three dots is ES6 syntax sugar called [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

It allows you to create copy of an object.

> **NOTE**: It will create copy only at first level in depth.

Your case with comments:

```
export const setName = action => {

  // return new action object which will passed 
  // to all reducers
  return {
    type: "SET_NAME",

    // unpack action object
    ...action
  };
};
```

In general, `...action` "unpack" properties so you can make copy of object with new values of properties which you need.

But, if you pass `action` object with already defined property `type` - this command won't be return action with updated type (`"SET_STATE"`) value. You should swap this two lines to return action with new `type` (as probably you want to do, but I'm sure it's not the best practice).

So, your output should be:

```
export const setName = action => {
  return {
    ...action,
    type: "SET_NAME",
  };
};
```

If your `action` object doesn't have `type` property - your code should work properly.

Hope it will helps.